# floats overlapping when negative margins are used

Tags: css, css-float, margin, overlap

Here's the markup:

```
<div>
    <a href="google.com">my link</a>
    <span>Testing content.</span> 
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div > * {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

div{

    margin-top:200px;
}
```

Note: The div is here just for demonstrating purposes to bring all the content back down so we can see it.

If I use a positive value for margin-top, say `50px`, bot the `a` and `span` are pushed down by 50 pixels an don't overlap each other.

If I use a negative value for margin-top, say `-50px`, both are pulled up by 50px, but they also overlap each other.

Why does this happen, and how do I prevent it?

Edit, some more info:

- Unfortunately, I cant put the `a` or `span` in a wrapper.
- I need to keep the floats as I need to reorganize the flow.
- I need to push the `a` and `span` upwards.

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xsSVX/

Comment: How do you want it to look? My first interpretation was well, get rid of float and make them inline. But that's probably not what you want.

Comment: I had to keep the floats as I need to reorganize the flow in the document. However, if you put a positive margin `50px`, you will see that the floats are pushed down and don't overlap. In my case, I simply need to be able to use a negative margin without the 2 floats overlapping, or some way to push the floats upwards without them being in a wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
div > * {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Gives the div some extra body..

http://jsfiddle.net/xsSVX/6/

Comment: This seems to have worked. Can you explain why the "extra body" is needed?

Comment: Because a and span are inline tags they don't have a HasLayout [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)